# Как сделать текст наравне с иконкой?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

[image: как сделать текст на равне с иконкой]

Помогите новичку вот код:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <img src="img/Векторный смарт-объект копия.png"> город
          </li>
          <li>
            вул. пушкина 2 оф. 5
          </li>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li> <img src="img/call-answer копия.png"> +38 097 63 313 46
          </li>
          <li>
            +38 097 63 313 46
          </li>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li> <img src="img/close-envelope копия.png"> 3455@gmail.com
          </li>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Да bootstrap 3.4.0

Comment: все теги в порядке. да по задумке

Comment: Верстка кривая...

Comment: тег img и текст обернуть по отдельности в тег р и задать им display:flex; и только потом уже расположить их в li

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так

Оборачиваем изображение и текст по отдельности в блочный тег и родителю указываем что он flex и всё

Но это плохая практика так как картинки не очень хорошо отображаются на некоторых устройствах, особенно на ретина ...но там поможет [srcset](https://webref.ru/html/img/srcset)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

li p {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50" alt="">
    </p>
    <p>+38 780 32 324 32</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50" alt="">
    </p>
    <p>Город Название Улица Название Дом Номер</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50" alt="">
    </p>
    <p>myemail@gmail.com</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю тут будет правильно использовать не картинки, а шрифт с различными значками. Сам [шрифт](https://fontawesome.com/).
Примерно так:

```css
i{
color: green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <ul>
        <p><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> Г.Пушкин, ул.Пушкина, дом 5</p>
        <p><i class="fas fa-phone"></i> +7 900 123 45 67</p>
        <p><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> info@yourfomain.ru</p>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не плохо но желательно img

Comment: @masana123321
Тогда попробуй сделать так <br>                    
      `<p><img src="img/Векторный смарт-объект копия.png">Город <br> вул. пушкина 2 оф. 5</p>
      <p><img src="img/call-answer копия.png"> +38 097 63 313 46 <br>+38 097 63 313 46</p>
      <p><img src="img/close-envelope копия.png">3455@gmail.com</p>
    ` и подогнать размер `img{width: x%;}`